# Calculus question proving $f(1)=f(2)$ from an inequality.

Tags: calculus

$Let $ $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \hspace{0.5em}$3 times differentiable and $2f(x)\geq f(1)+f(2), \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $

Prove $f(1)=f(2)$

This is probably done via the MVT but I've tried lots of intervals including $x$ in them but that lead to too many cases and nothing of substance came up. I also tried the min max Value Theorem. Maybe I'm missing something or the exercise is faulty (it wouldn't be the first time). Thoughts?

Comment: Use the hypothesis for $x=1$ and $x=2$.

Comment: Differentiability is a red herring here.

Answer (score 1):

Well in such questions involving functions with conditions, the best strategy is to plug in certain values that seem to take us further. We'll start by plugging in $x=1$ (since the condition is true $\forall x \in \mathbb R$:
$$2f(1)\ge f(1)+f(2)$$
So, we have
$$\color{blue}{f(1) \ge f(2)}$$
Plugging in $x = 2$:
$$2f(2)\ge f(1)+f(2)$$
$$\color{blue}{f(2) \ge f(1)}$$
From the highlighted inequalities, we get:
$$\color{green}{f(1) = f(2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as an answer since I cannot comment.

Note that the inequality in question holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Try using only the inequality, and nothing else?